# Implementing service charges/paying 2 separate accounts with Braintree

Tags: php, android, braintree

Just wondering if its possible to apply your own service charges to Braintree or have the transaction being split in between 2 separate accounts.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you looking for a Marketplace functionality to payout clients? Notably, many merchants have found success with [Hyperwallet](https://www.hyperwallet.com/). PayPal also provides a Payouts API for these exact situations, as well. In these cases, you'd charge the full transaction in Braintree, and then payout the respective balance to the client or other account using one of those third-party solutions.

Comment: That sounds similar to what I'm looking for. I just discovered Stripe Connect as well so i have a fair bit of comparing ahead of me. Thanks bud!